# Using PreferenceActivity in API 15 and later

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-preferences, android-api-levels

In my Android app, I want to make a preference activity using `PreferenceActivity` because I am addressing phones where `androidx` is not available (`PreferenceActivity` is indeed not deprecated until API 28). However, the essential method `addPreferencesFromResource()`, which I saw being used in nearly every tutorial on that, is deprecated in API 15 already. The same applies for other methods.

How to use `PreferenceActivity` in APIs 15 to 28? Is there a tutorial somewhere or can this be explained briefly? Thank you!

Comment: ```PreferenceFragment``` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45066520/whats-the-proper-way-to-setup-an-android-preferencefragment

Comment: Thanks. But I don't quite understand the answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45067104/10126596 because it contains only a few code snippets and seems to be adapted to the question author who already knows much more about this topic than me. The answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51854023/10126596 seems not to be appropriate because it uses `PreferenceFragmentCompat` which is a part of `androidx` according to https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/PreferenceFragmentCompat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16363093/10126596) are links to documentations of some old APIs. I looked up at `docs-19_r02/docs/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment`:

```
public class ActivityPreferences extends Activity {
    protected void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.replace (android.R.id.content, new FragmentPreferences());
        transaction.commit();
    }
}

public class FragmentPreferences extends PreferenceFragment {
    public void onCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        this.addPreferencesFromResource (R.xml.preferences);
    }
}
```